# how to print an extra element in 1d array without bound exception?

Tags: java, arrays

at the beginning I read the file and used split() method and stored each value in 1d array. i must store index 0 and 1 in a string value ans index 2,3 and 4 must be stored in 1d array because "supervisor" object arguments contains two string values(name and id) and 1d array (interests) the problem is at row 0 there is an extra interest (3 interests) and at row 1 and 2 there are two interests.
what i thought about is to store the interests in an arraylist (because the size is not static )and convert it back to 1d array but it did not work 
tries to store the interests in 2d array and convert t back to 1d array but it did not work , while splitting the file i splitted (, and #) but i noticed at the end of every interest there is a #
so i kept the # and thought if i can do an if condition while reading the file. is there any simple idea to avoid the error?

the file supervisor.txt contains:

```
00023, Dr. Haneen,  artificial intelligent, data mining, pattern recognition#
00013, Dr. Manar, database, network#
00011, Dr. Hajar, software engineering, games#
```

Code

```
public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {

    File supervisorFile=new File("supervisor.txt");
    if (!supervisorFile.exists()) {
        System.out.println("Sorry the file is not found!");  //checks if the file exists if no it terminates the program
        System.exit(0);
    }

    supervisor sup=null;
    String[]supArray=null;

    Scanner supRead=new Scanner(supervisorFile);//read supervisor file

    while (supRead.hasNext()) {
        supArray=supRead.nextLine().split(",");
        sup=addSupervisor(supArray);
        //System.out.println(sup.toString()); 
    }
}

public static supervisor addSupervisor(String[]arr){
    String id=arr[0];
    String name=arr[1];
    String[] interest=new String[3];

    for (int i = 0; i < interest.length; i++) { //here i tried to store all the interests
        interest[i]=arr[2]+arr[3]+arr[4]; 
    }//it prints artificial intelligent data mining pattern recognition# and then an indexOutOfBoundsException

    return new supervisor(id,name,interest);
}
```

Comment: Are all those Strings you wanna split in the same line?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use `split` with a limit parameter.

```
class Supervisor{
    final String id;
    final String name;
    String[] fields;

    Supervisor(String id, String name, String[] fields) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.fields = fields;
    }
}

Path path = Paths.get("supervisor.txt");
List<Supervisor> supervisors = Files.lines(path, Charset.defaultCharset())
    .filter(l -> l.endsWith("#"))
    .map(l -> l.substring(0, l.length() - 1)) // Remove #
    .map(l -> l.split(",\\s*", 3)) // "00013", "Dr. Manar", "database, network"
    .filter(w -> w.length == 3)
    .map(w -> new Supervisor(w[0], w[1], w[2].split(",\s*")))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

Use split & ArraysList

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ToStringBuilder;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ToStringStyle;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;

@AllArgsConstructor
class Supervisor {

    String id;
    String name;
    List<String> interest;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(this, ToStringStyle.NO_CLASS_NAME_STYLE);
    }
}

public class AMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String id, name, line;
        String[] arr;
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file/supervisor.txt"))) {
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                arr = line.trim().split(",");
                list.addAll(Arrays.asList(arr));
                if (list.size() > 2) {
                    id = list.get(0); // get id
                    list.remove(0); // remove id 
                    name = list.get(0); // get name
                    list.remove(0); // remove name
                    System.out.println(new Supervisor(id, name, list));
                }
                list.clear(); // clear all
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
[id=00023,name= Dr. Haneen,interest=[  artificial intelligent,  data mining,  pattern recognition#]]
[id=00013,name= Dr. Manar,interest=[ database,  network#]]
[id=00011,name= Dr. Hajar,interest=[ software engineering,  games#]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second and third line only has 4 Strings split up by a comma. That makes it 4 Strings in the Array. In your addSupervisor methode you are trying to access arr[4], the 5th String, which is out of bound.

Answer (score 0):

You get an error because you are trying to use `arr[4]`, but wioth the lines 2 and 3 the size of the array will be 4, so the maximum index you can use is 3.

I don't know for sue what `Supervisor` is, but would this work:

```
public static supervisoraddSupervisor(String[]arr){
    String id=arr[0];
    String name=arr[1];
    String[] interest=new String[arr.length - 2];

    for (int i = 0; i < interest.length; i++) { 
        interest[i]=arr[i + 2]; 
    }

    return new supervisor(id,name,interest);
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVPBbuIwED03XzHKXoKyTQMcWQ6VutJeeuKIOEwTE4Y6djSewFaIb2cnScO2Eq0vtl/ezHtvrOzxgPf78vVyobrxLLBXIGuFbPbIjG9hEUVN@2KpgMJiCPCM5OA0YkFQdDt4KqHWL8lKmFy13gByFSayY38M8PtvYRoh3xXeXRmhbXoJWIIzRxjxU5zn@Wwe/4T4iTP4g84YpzeIkYW2VBBaICfGWqqMk45YoiDU5LRBd21QxLADNoWvHHXKP@LzIrrDsly1jeEDBc/JaGCiGW/4mt0yNr0ae0aHPIq/YDDd2Rk5en79Tm32hdz8ptz0/xz2g1zwWzkiGzCuIp0Nv4eusDbhO@G5Cp@jWy/3mT8aQObJKQJdAwJULhVb55vFR9Spbo9PP@GarHskNkGWH2IpMbPqXHZwDzOt6Eu2niFROpAOIV/o9uta/U5XME0ncIKHh53iStGGpgTxGsUrgNaC7My1LvSduzUia9r0RgnSThp6wnlwsHoLYurMt5I1alSsS6hMY4jTLl9/GP6HTPwQJRnbTvq5ni@Xfw)

Comment: thank you very much it worked but I wonder why we subtract 2 from the array length and added 2 again while adding the elements?

Comment: We subtract 2 because the length of the interest is the same that the input, minus the id and the name, which means 2.
We add 2, because of the same reason. The indexes 0 and 1 are the id and the name. So you need to start after, which is 2.

Answer (score 0):

First you should get the line and then work with it like you do. The problem is in the loop for where you suppose all the "supervisor" have 3 interests. Also you are storing all the interest in the first pos of the array:

```
for (int i = 0; i < interest.length; i++) { //here i tried to store all the interests
        interest[i]=arr[2]+arr[3]+arr[4]; 
}
```

So I think you should use a function like this:

```
private static String[] extractInterest(String[] line) {
        String[] res = new String[line.length - 2]; //There are two index that haven't got interest

        for(int i = 0; i<res.length; ++i) {
            res[i] = line[i+2].replaceFirst(" ", "").replace("#","");
        }

        return res;
    }
```

And this is the "main":

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        File file = new File("Data.txt");
        try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(file)) { //Will close the sc automatically
            String[] line;
            while(sc.hasNext()) {
                line = sc.nextLine().split(",");

                int id = Integer.parseInt(line[0]);
                String name = line[1].replaceFirst(" ",""); //For delete first " "
                String[] interest = extractInterest(line);

                Supervisor s = new Supervisor(id,name,interest);
                System.out.println(s.toString());
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

A final advice, Java classes names must begin with uppercase by agreement. So you should change the name of your class "supervisor" to "Supervisor"

Comment: also thank you for reminding me to correct the mistake I made for naming a class